# Postfix alias mail receives messages only from local mailboxes

Tags: postfix, dovecot, quota, aliases

I've installed a Postfix-Dovecot mail server following a guide ([How to Set Up an Email Server With Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/)) that defines a simple  setup with virtual mailboxes and a database that maps virtual domains, virtual users and virtual aliases.

Below, the server domain is called `server.com`. The mail server handles also another domain, here called `example.com`.

`mail@example.com` has an alias, `alias@example.com`.
This is what happens:

1. mail from `mail@server.com` to `alias@example.com`: delivered
2. mail from `mymail@gmail.com` to `main@example.com`: delivered
3. mail `mymail@gmail.com` to `alias@example.com`: **rejected**

In the last case the reply is:

```
554 5.7.1 <alias@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: Unknown user
```

In other words, the alias receives messages only from local mailboxes.

The recipient restrictions are the following:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        check_policy_service inet:localhost:12345
```

Answer (score 0):

So far this problem seems to be reported only once [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/), where the cause was identified in the Dovecot quota check.

In this case it's the last of the *smtpd_recipient_restrictions* :

`check_policy_service inet:localhost:12345`

Actually, the problem disappears after removing it.

When the quota check is in place, the log reveals the following:

```
dovecot: quota-status(alias@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(alias@example.com): Started userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: master in: USER#0111#011alias@example.com#011service=quota-status
dovecot: auth: static(alias@example.com): Performing userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: sql(alias@example.com): Performing passdb lookup
dovecot: auth-worker: conn unix:auth-worker: Handling PASSL request
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(alias@example.com): Performing passdb lookup
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(alias@example.com): query: SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='alias@example.com';
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(alias@example.com): unknown user
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(alias@example.com): Finished passdb lookup
dovecot: auth-worker: conn unix:auth-worker: Finished
dovecot: auth: sql(alias@example.com): Finished passdb lookup
dovecot: auth: static(alias@example.com): Finished userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: userdb out: NOTFOUND#0111
dovecot: quota-status(alias@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(alias@example.com): auth USER input: 
dovecot: quota-status(alias@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(alias@example.com): Userdb lookup failed
postfix/smtpd: NOQUEUE: reject: 554 5.7.1 <alias@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: Unknown user; from=<mymailgmail.com> to=<alias@example.com>
```

The problem is that query defined in `etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` searches the email only in the `virtual_users` table:

```
query: SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='alias@example.com';
```

The [Linode tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/) referenced above states at some point:

> To use an alias as the username:
>
> Add the alias as the source and destination email address to the virtual_aliases table.
> Change the `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` file’s password_query value to:
>
> ```
>    password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email=(SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source = '%u');
> ```

I opted for a slightly different solution, making an UNION of the two queries in order to search a virtual user first, then a virtual alias:

```
password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%u' \
 UNION SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email=(SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source = '%u');
```

This works just fine. Below is an excerpt of the log:

```
dovecot: quota-status(alias@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(alias@example.com): Started userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: master in: USER#0114#011alias@example.com#011service=quota-status
dovecot: auth: static(alias@example.com): Performing userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: sql(alias@example.com): Performing passdb lookup
dovecot: auth: sql(alias@example.com): username changed alias@example.com -> mail@example.com
dovecot: auth: sql(mail@example.com): Finished passdb lookup
dovecot: auth: static(mail@example.com): Finished userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: userdb out: USER#0114#011mail@example.com#011uid=5000#011gid=5000#011home=/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/mail
dovecot: auth-worker: conn unix:auth-worker: Handling PASSL request
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(alias@example.com): Performing passdb lookup
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(alias@example.com): query: SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='alias@example.com' UNION SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email=(SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='alias@example.com');
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(alias@example.com): username changed alias@example.com -> mail@example.com
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(mail@example.com): Finished passdb lookup
dovecot: auth-worker: conn unix:auth-worker: Finished
dovecot: quota-status(alias@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(alias@example.com): auth USER input: mail@example.com uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/mail
dovecot: quota-status(alias@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(alias@example.com): Finished userdb lookup
dovecot: quota-status(alias@example.com): changed username to mail@example.com
dovecot: quota-status(mail@example.com): Effective uid=5000, gid=5000, home=/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/mail
dovecot: lmtp(mail@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(mail@example.com): Started userdb lookup
dovecot: lmtp(mail@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(mail@example.com): auth USER input: mail@example.com uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/mail
dovecot: lmtp(mail@example.com): auth-master: userdb lookup(mail@example.com): Finished userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: master in: USER#0112#011mail@example.com#011service=lmtp
dovecot: auth: static(mail@example.com): Performing userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: sql(mail@example.com): Performing passdb lookup
dovecot: auth: sql(mail@example.com): Finished passdb lookup
dovecot: auth: static(mail@example.com): Finished userdb lookup
dovecot: auth: userdb out: USER#0112#011mail@example.com#011uid=5000#011gid=5000#011home=/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/mail
dovecot: auth-worker: conn unix:auth-worker: Handling PASSL request
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(mail@example.com): Performing passdb lookup
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(mail@example.com): query: SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='mail@example.com' UNION SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email=(SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='mail@example.com');
dovecot: auth-worker: sql(mail@example.com): Finished passdb lookup
dovecot: auth-worker: conn unix:auth-worker: Finished
dovecot: lmtp(mail@example.com): lmtp-server: conn unix: rcpt mail@example.com: Effective uid=5000, gid=5000, home=/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/mail
dovecot: lmtp(mail@example.com): lmtp-server: conn unix: rcpt mail@example.com: Mailbox INBOX: Mailbox opened because: lib-lda delivery
dovecot: lmtp(mail@example.com): saved mail to INBOX
postfix/lmtp: to=<mail@example.com>, orig_to=<alias@example.com>, relay=server.example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], status=sent
```